# How to get address of value pointed by pointer from that pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference

Sry, this must be answered somewhere but I haven't find it.

I have a code:

```
const int * tableCards[9];
int hand1card1 = 0;
tableCards[0] = & hand1card1;
int hand1card2 = 1;
tableCards[1] = & hand1card2;
int * flop1 = & tableCard[0];
tableCards[2] = flop1;
cout << * flop1 << endl;
cout << * tableCards[2] << endl;
flop1++;
cout << * flop1 << endl;
cout << * tableCards[2] << endl;

tableCard[48] is an array of pointers to ints
```

This code works, but I want to change the line `tableCards[2] = flop1;` to make the `* tableCards[2]` return the actual value of element pointed by `* flop1`. In this code the *flop1 returns the value I want but *tableCards[2] remains the same after incrementing the flop1.

I thought that `tableCards[2] = & (* flop1);` will assign the address of the value pointed by *flop1 to int pointer tableCards[2] but after incrementing flop1, the tableCards[2] value remains the same. I don't want to use array of pointers on pointers instead array of pointers, because 4/9 values needed are just ints, not pointers on ints.

Edit: Note that tableCards[9] is different array than tableCard[48]. And sry, this question must be confusing when I see the comments and answers.

Comment: It is VERY confusing what you are trying to do there. Do you really want an array of pointers to constant ints (`const int* []`)? Does that code even compile? In fact, you are assigning a `const int**` to a `const int*`.
Correction to myself, it might compile, but it's still not recommended.

Comment: sry, tableCard[48] is an array of pointers to ints

Comment: It looks confusing, but it's working without problems, I don't even know, what is not recommended. My only problem is to assign an address of *flop1 value to another int pointer to change that anothers pointer value when I increment flop1 so flop1 points on another value. :(

Comment: When you assign a pointer to another pointer, you are just copying the address contained in the source pointer. The receiving variable holds only what the source variable contained, therefore, getting the address of source pointer is impossible without more information.

Maybe if you used an array of pointer references... Don't know if that's even possible, though

Comment: I just want to have a pointer that changes its dereferenced value depending on the target of the pointed pointer. And I can't have an array of pointers to pointers because some values in that array would be only pointers to ints.

Comment: Your explanations are not clear.  I've tried to cover most potential scenarios in my answer.  I hope it helps. =/

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't compile:

```
int * flop1 = & tableCard[0];
```

The type of `tableCard[0]` is `int*`, so when you reference it with `&` it becomes `int**`.  You are assigning that to an `int*`.  At the very least it should be generating a compiler warning.

So, `flop1` points to the address `tableCard[0]`, `*flop1` gives you the value (a pointer) stored at `tableCard[0]`, and `**flop1` gives you the value that `tableCard[0]` points to.  But because you have given `flop1` the wrong type (`int*` instead of `int**`), you can't do this.

I base this on the comment you made that you have another array:

```
int * tableCard[48];
```

I think what you meant to do is:

```
int * flop1 = tableCard[0];
tableCards[2] = flop1;
```

Now, when you increment `flop1` it just changes the pointer.  The pointer at `tableCards[2]` will still point to the same value as `tableCard[0]` points to.

But THIS is very naughty:

```
flop1++;
cout << * flop1 << endl;
```

`flop1` is the pointer stored at `tableCard[0]`.  When you increment that and then use it, you are treating it as an array.  Maybe it is?  But probably it's not.  You do not know what memory `flop1` now points to.

*[edit]* After having more of a think about what this code might be trying to achieve...

So indeed, if you are expecting `flop1` to now point to the second array element, you need to use a double-pointer (`int**`).  This means that `flop1` is now an iterator in your `tableCard` array, rather than an element...  So when you increment it, it now points to the pointer stored at `tableCard[1]` while `tableCards[2]` still contains the value of (but doesn't point to) `tableCard[0]`.

```
int ** flop1 = & tableCard[0];
tableCards[2] = *flop1;
cout << **flop1 << endl;
cout << *tableCards[2] << endl;
flop1++;
cout << **flop1 << endl;
cout << *tableCards[2] << endl;
```

Further edits, based on inference once again...  I suspect that maybe you want the `tableCard` array to be defined as:

```
int tableCard[48];
```

In that case, your code should otherwise be correct with no other changes required.  Well, presumably.  The whole lot seems a bit suspect.

Comment: sry, tableCard[48] is an array of pointers to ints, I edited it, sry

Comment: What do you call an array of pointers to ints, @LukasSalich? We are aware that you are using an array of pointers to ints (int*[]), and the answers clearly assume that.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't pick up the difference between `tableCards` and `tableCard`.  Not a good idea to use such similar names.  Anyway, same applies.  If all your card arrays are int pointers, look at the edit near the end of my answer about using double pointers.  I'll fix it to use `tableCard[0]`

Comment: The problem is that I can't use double pointers because I already have an array of just single pointers in it. The problems came out when I tried to use sets for faster erasing and inserting. I am totally stuck so I will rewrite everything on vectors and won't need array of pointers to allocate sets elements.

Comment: But an array of single pointers is the same as a double pointer.  *ie* `int *tableCard[48];` is kinda the same thing as `int **tableCard = new int*[48];`.  I think you are having trouble understanding pointers and arrays.  You haven't explained why you are storing arrays of int pointers instead of just ints.  What does the array `tableCard` actually represent?